# Empty href in cancel link on careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was trying to see if I can be selected for testing/using careers, but when my SO account didn't worked I tried to use my GitHUB one, just to see that the "cancel" button don't do a thing. Checking the source code found this:

```
<a href="" class="cancel">cancel</a>
```

this could be actually an go back JS function or just filling the href with "http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one" or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed. No javascript magic (well, maybe there once was). But it was just normal broken. Thanks.